# Spanish resource RESX file for mutiple countries

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization, asp.net-core-localization

I'm working on a .Net Core project using Localization Globalization settings oriented to the settings on the Browser. I just got a problem, that I have a Default.es.resx for example. That works when the browser is configured to Spanish, but, if the user configures to Spanish(Mexico) or Spanish(Argentina) for example it gets the default language that is English. Is there a way to have just one file to be used for every type of spanish language?

Comment: Just solved it, simply used a substring(0,2) to get the "es" from the session.

Comment: According to the docs, it should [revert to parent culture by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#culture-fallback-behavior), or you can use `CultureInfo.Parent`